# pthread.h in a kernel driver for OS X (using Xcode)

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel, pthreads, driver

I am trying to port the fantastic ASUS XONAR-series driver for Linux, written by Clemens Ladisch, to Mac OSX.

Right now, a very rough version that compiles is available at: github.com/i3roly/CMI8788

My question is regarding the pthread.h header for OSX. By default, including pthread.h tries to define a structure that is markedly different from the one included through the IOKit drivers. for brevity i will use an informative post from a github post(https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/issues/364#issuecomment-255438891):

```
#include <pthread.h> 
   #include <sys/_types/_mach_port_t.h> 
      typedef __darwin_mach_port_t mach_port_t;
```

versus

```
#include <IOKit/audio/IOAudioDevice.h>
   #include <IOKit/IOService.h>
        #include <IOKit/IORegistryEntry.h>
           #include <IOKit/IOTypes.h>
              #include <IOKit/system.h>
                  #include <mach/mach_types.h>
                      #include <mach/host_info.h>
                          #include <mach/message.h>
                              #include <mach/port.h>

/*
 *  For kernel code that resides outside of Mach proper, we opaque the
 *  port structure definition.
 */
struct ipc_port;


typedef struct ipc_port         *ipc_port_t;

#define IPC_PORT_NULL           ((ipc_port_t) 0UL)
#define IPC_PORT_DEAD           ((ipc_port_t)~0UL)
#define IPC_PORT_VALID(port) \
    ((port) != IPC_PORT_NULL && (port) != IPC_PORT_DEAD)

typedef ipc_port_t              mach_port_t;
```

now, i can get around this by doing

```
#define _MACH_PORT_T
#include <pthread.h>
```

but i am not sure if this is a safe solution, since to me it seems the pthreads API for Xcode implies it is only to be used for user-land programs. is this assumption wrong? is using this macro to get around the redefinition problem a reasonable one?

have others tried to write kernel land drivers for OSX using pthreads, and encountered this issue? any insight would be appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid question.

i don't know why i didn't remind myself that you CANNOT USE PTHREADS IN KERNEL, especially when i have experience building the linux kernel (which should have served as an easy reminder that YOU CANNOT DO THIS AND IT IS A BAD IDEA)

*hits self over the head with a slipper*

i have no idea why this didn't click yesterday.